# Как исключить дергания при переключении табов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть блок с **табами** При переходе на активную закладку - заголовок должен выделяться более жирным цветом, но при таком выделение происходит дергание с микросдвигом всех пунктов меню - получается неприятно глазу. [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2793/)
Как сделать так, чтобы этот микросдвиг исключить и пункт меню все также выделялся жирным, причем **позволяя этому пункту быть произвольной ширины**? (чтобы пунктам меню позволить быть произвольными и не зависеть от длины содержимого)

```css
.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  color: #c4c2c2;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: none;
}

.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  border: none;
  color: #595959;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/inline-elements-shifting-when-made-bold-on-hover

Comment: @soledar10 очень хорошее решение

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @soledar10 за [супер изящное решение проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/inline-elements-shifting-when-made-bold-on-hover) - цитируя перевод: "идея состоит в том, чтобы зарезервировать место для жирного (или любых `:hover` состояний стилей) состояния псевдоэлемента `:after` используя атрибут `title`"
[Фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2798/)

```
.nav-tabs>li>a:after {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -1px;
  content: attr(title);
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```css
.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  color: #c4c2c2;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: none;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:after {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -1px;
  content: attr(title);
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  border: none;
  color: #595959;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" title="Home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#profile" title="Profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#messages" title="Messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#settings" title="Settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

Если честно, для меня это до сих пор как какая-то магия и не до конца понимаю почему именно так все происходит

Answer (score -1):

чтобы не *дергалось*, задайте фиксированную ширину для табов

```
<a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

.nav-tabs>li>a{
    width: 85px; // например
    color: #c4c2c2;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: почему не читаете задание "причем позволяя этому пункту быть произвольной ширины?" минус за невнимательность

Comment: _например_  - специально написал, а по делу, когда блок без фиксированного размера или `min-width` и т.д. , то при изменении шрифта, в нашем случае жирный шрифт, то будет и сдвигаться контент. Начальный уровень CSS.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov в вопросе явно написано - **позволяя этому пункту быть произвольной ширины**. ваши **например** тут ни к чему

Comment: Sergey Novikov посмотрите на ответ @soledar10 в комментариях выше и мотайте на ус продвинутый уровень css, как это сделал я

Comment: @Вася прочитал это ещё 18 часов назад и сделал для себя выводы, а у вас я вижу ещё пожар не затушен.